# Gstreamer | Appsink vs Kmssink performance mismatch

Tags: opencv, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

Below is a pipeline which is **capturing the 1080p** input video data from thee RTSP stream, **decoding**, and **displaying** it to the output device.

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://admin:888888@192.168.5.28:5006/udp/av0_0 latency=0 io-mode=4 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! omxh264dec ! queue max-size-bytes=0 ! fpsdisplaysink name=fpssink text-overlay=false video-sink="kmssink bus-id=fd4a0000.zynqmp-display fullscreen-overlay=1" sync=true -v
```

The above pipeline is working fine and **I am using Kmssink as a sink element**. The **overall pipeline is giving me ~25FPS** performance number.

Now I wanted to process the frames before displaying it on the device SO I am using the **OpenCV API'**s to capture the frames from the **same gst pipeline**.

The **modified pipeline is below where I am using appsink instead of kmssink** because appsink is required in **OpenCV to make the frames available to the application**.

```
videoCapture cap(rtspsrc location=rtsp://admin:888888@192.168.5.28:5006/udp/av0_0 latency=0 latency=0 io-mode=4 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! omxh264dec internal-entropy-buffers=5 low-latency=1 ! videoconvert ! appsink sync=false async=false");
```

Problem:
**appsink** element is giving very **low performance ~ 2 FPS** as compare to **kmssink** element
Is there any way to optimize the **appsink** performance or some other way to optimize the performance in this pipeline?

Any input will be highly appricicated

Comment: What platform? Could be that be downloading data from GPU to host memory slows you down. The first pipeline is probably decoding and displaying inside the GPU, not transferring to host.

Comment: @FlorianZwoch Data is coming from the IP camera via RTSP protocol. Yes, the first pipeline is to capture the 1080p video data, decode, and display.  The platform I am using is FPGA

Comment: The first pipeline is working well. But when I am switching  to OpenCV due to the appsink  element I am getting very less performance

Comment: So then its probably your software videoconvert and data transfer from GPU to host memory.

Comment: Data transfer is proper. but I am not sure about videoconvert. thing is if I use videoscale to reduce the resolution from 1080p to 480p and pass it to videoconvert then it is working fine and providing ~25FPS